# Different radiation intensities from a black body

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, radiation, thermal-radiation

I am a high school student and was wondering about the radiation curve of a black body. Why do the emitted wavelengths from a black body have different intensities? What happens at the atomic level that makes some wavelengths stronger than others resulting in a radiation peak?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/645671/247642, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/639995/247642, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/644253/247642, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/648273/247642

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: The density of electromagnetic modes increasing with frequency, while the number of photons contained in each mode drops with frequency.**

According to the [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation#Planck%27s_law_of_black-body_radiation), the spectral radiance is given by
$$
B(\nu, T)=\frac{2\nu^2}{c^2}\frac{h\nu}{\exp\left(\frac{h\nu}{k_B T}\right)-1}$$
The factor $\nu^2$ originates from the density of states, i.e., the density of electromagnetic modes per frequency interval, which increases with frequency, $\nu$. On the other hand, factor $h\nu/\left[\exp\left(\frac{h\nu}{k_B T}\right)-1\right]$ is nearly constant at low frequencies and decays expinentially when $h\nu\gg k_BT$: $h\nu/\left[\exp\left(\frac{h\nu}{k_B T}\right)-1\right]\approx h\nu\exp\left(-\frac{h\nu}{k_B T}\right)$. Thus, at small frequencies the radiance increases, but then drops - hence there is a peak in between. In essence, it is the competition between the density of electromagnetic modes increasing with frequency, while the number of photons contained in each mode drops with frequency.